# How to specify the GraphQL schema in the HTTP client of the IntelliJ 2022.2 EAP release?

Tags: intellij-idea, graphql

Where and how do I specify the schema definition file for GraphQL when using the HTTP client?

Comment: This feature should be available in [2022.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion) build. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265917 and https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/06/intellij-idea-2022-2-eap-5 .

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I know the issue and the blog which you mentioned. But I cannot find how to specify which schema file shall be used.